# JavaScript Create Calendar Table in DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have created a table with 6 rows and  5 cols. The table is created for each month having presumably  different number of days. I would like each col to display a date from 1-30 or 1-31 (depending on the month).

This is what  I have so far:

```
function daysOfMonth(){
  var table= " ";
  var rows= 3;
   var cols=6;
  var number= 31;
  for(var r=0; r<rows; r++){
    table+= "<tr>";
        for(var c=0; c<=cols; c++){
                table+= "<td>" + c +"</td>"
      // each col should display number for(var i=0l i<=number; i++)
    }

table+= "</tr>"
 }
document.write('<table>' + table +"</table>")

};// func end
```

Here is a codepen   http://codepen.io/cb42/pen/KNJWrd

Comment: better create a fiddle to show what you have done. Also show the expected output(image)

Comment: http://www.javascriptsource.com/time-date/calendar.html

Answer (score 0):

As i've see your code get two little bugs, solved in my simple example.
By this poin could you try to make it better. But i expect it helps you to understand how to make a calendar.

https://jsfiddle.net/cyzbhkjs/

```
function daysOfMonth(){
  var _table= "<p>jol</p> ";
  var rows= 5;
   var cols=6;
  var c= 1;
  var daysMonth =31;
  for(var r=0; r<rows; r++){
    _table+= "<tr>";
        for(var i=0; i<=cols; i++){
        if(c<=daysMonth){
            _table+= "<td>" + c +"</td>";
        }else{
        break;
        }

          c++;
      // each col should display number at i
    }


_table+= "</tr>";

 }
 document.getElementById('calendar').innerHTML = '<table>hola' + _table +'</table>';

};
  daysOfMonth();
```

Thanks

Comment: awesome! Im working on adding the weekday (Sun, Mon, Tues etc) along with the calendar any idea how to go about that?

Comment: then you need to get first wich day is the first day of month, if is monday, tuesday... And then start the for at position of this.